# AppEngine serving from '/workspace' instead of '/srv', but only on some instances

Tags: google-app-engine

One of our PHP GAE apps stopped working today, because the path that GAE serves our app from changed from `/srv/` to `/workspace/`. In an ideal world we wouldn’t have depended on that path, but… details.

Does anyone have further info on the change? Does GAE consider this an 'implementation detail'? It doesn’t seem to have reached all our instances yet, which will make managing the change a little painful, and I couldn't see it documented anywhere.

(Apologies, this doesn't really feel a great fit for StackExchange/Overflow, but Google says I should post any 'technical questions' here....).

Both instances are running appEngineRelease 1.9.71 weirdly.

Comment: At what channel did "Google says I should post any 'technical questions' here"? Cause what you are describing appears to be a bug, so it might be a good idea for you to open a bug report in [Google's Issue Tracker for App Engine](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187191&template=0) so that this can be addressed by Google's Engineering Team if that is the case. Btw, I did some searching on issue tracker and there does not appear to be a bug with that problem already in there.

Comment: @RafaelLemos on their "community support" page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/community thanks though, will post an issue in their tracker